# Team Viewer Control Button not working

Tags: 18.04, teamviewer

I am using Ubuntu 18+ version and accessing Windows 8.1, after connecting the control button for copy, paste and print like commands not working as expected.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu 18+ version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems issue due to Control button highlighting feature. Try turning off the feature. Install dconf-editor on ubuntu and in that setting->mouse->turn off the highlighting.